# Newtonsoft Json Deserialize ignores NullValueHandling.Ignore

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have the following class:

```
    public class Msg
    {
        public int logType { get; set; }
        public DateTime logTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string value { get; set; }

    }
```

and I am trying to deserialize a string which might or might not have the the `value` set (property not existant). I thought the option `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` would result in not having the property `string` being created while deserializing?

Unfortunately I see the following:

```
logTime {28.03.2020 15:10:39}   System.DateTime
logType 1   int
value   null    string
```

Any idea or did I get the option wrong?

Comment: What is the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Something like that, with or without the `value` property. `{
    "logType": 1,
    "logTime": "2020-03-28T15:10:39Z",
    "value": "abc"
}`

Comment: @p1ngu1n, `value` in your JSON is not null. Are you sure that's the correct JSON?

Comment: @HeyJude, sorry I might have written that misleading.. So m JSON looks
- either this way `{ "logType": 1, "logTime": "2020-03-28T15:10:39Z", "value": "abc" }`  
- or this way `{ "logType": 1, "logTime": "2020-03-28T15:10:39Z" }`.

Both can happen and if the value property is missing I don't want it to appear after deserialization as an empty property in the Msg class.

Comment: @p1ngu1n, think of it for a second: what value *do* you want it to have? After all, `value` is part of your class, so it must have either no value (i.e., null) or *some* non-null value. It can't be just gone.